# Connector for splitting GND and VCC to six servos

Tags: connector

I have one ground wire and one voltage wire that needs to be split into six separate pieces so I can connect each piece to a servos voltage an ground pins(which are male).

I basically need a wire jumper(female) that I put one ground or power pin into, then its outputs (female or male doesn't matter) go into the servos.

Note: Its output doesn't have to be six, but as long as the input to the wire jumper is one. I did research but found nothing

Servo stall current is 2.5 A at 6 V. During operation it is 1 A. Servos operate from a supply voltage from 4.8 V to 6 V.

Comment: Depending on size you might get two or three wires into a crimp connector, but not 6.  Typically for that you use a distribution board consisting of PCB mount connectors on a board with tracks that bus the power pins, while allowing unique signals to the data.   Ideally this would be a part of the board that is originating the servo signals.  Do be careful as not only can loose connections cause failure or mis-operation, depending on the power source shorting the power pins can be extremely hazardous.

Comment: Servo voltage, current, and distance from the supply, please?

Comment: servo has 2.5amp stall current at 6v, then at operating its 1amp an operates between 4.8-6v. Its about 1 feet away from the battery pack(source). May I get some links to see what you guys are talking about?

Comment: Can I use a terminal strip? One strip for power one for ground? Input the power into one hole, then connect the servos to the other ? SUch as this http://www.alliedelec.com/weco-323-hds-12/70211832/

Comment: https://www.servocity.com/html/servo_power_boards.html

Comment: you can use almost any connector so long as it can handle the current (most servos use 0.1" headers, so you could get some of those and solder some wires together)